# Different New Relic apps for single Apache instance w/ different Drupal instances per vhost

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, monitoring, newrelic

- I have a **single Apache** instance, with **multiple vhosts**.
- On each vhost I have a **different Drupal installation**.
- With the default NR installation, all the Drupal installations appear as one app.

What do I need to configure in order to make each Drupal instance appear as a different app?

Answer (score 1):

New Relic has an excellent set of instructions detailing how to set up multiple applications [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/configuration/php-directory-ini-settings)

You can accomplish this either via ini files, htaccess files, your httpd.conf, or API calls.